# Glide Library update issue

Tags: java, android, android-glide

I have a problem with glide library.

I am using glide library of 3.6.1 already. Now, I am trying to use another library which using glide version of 4.0.0. I am getting package not found errors in glide library. How should I resolve this issue?

> /Users/captainajay/keznotesapp/app/src/main/java/com/uolo/notes/noteobject/NoteObjectRecycleAdapter.java:748:
>   error: cannot find symbol
>
> Glide.with(context).load(R.drawable.facebook_rotate).asGif().into(imageNoteHolder.rotateCircle);
>                                                                               ^   symbol:   method asGif()   location: class
>   RequestBuilder

Comment: https://futurestud.io/tutorials/glide-4-upgrade-guide-from-glide-3-x

Answer (score 0):

The library has changed the way of use.
For under 4.0.0 you can use the old method as like below :

```
Glide.with(context)
                .load(url)
                .asBitmap()
                .fitCenter()
                .into(imageview);
```

But the newer version of **Glide** changed its method of use like below :

```
Glide.with(context)
                .load(imageURL)
                .apply(new RequestOptions().centerCrop().placeholder(placeholder))
                .into(imageView);
```

You should've included all the style within `.apply`.[Refer this link](http://bumptech.github.io/glide/doc/migrating.html#requestoptions)  for more details. And don't forget to add the annotation and implementation dependencies in the gradle.